# Checking for internet connection in VPC/ subnet using Boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, boto3

I need to be able to look at all VPCs in an account, and see which ones have internet access via NAT gateway/ Internet Gateway/ VPC peering connection.

I've thought about trying to look at each VPCs route table, manually check if any of the above connections exist, and then from there I am unsure.
I've thought about trying to Ping somehow but that seems unfeasible.
Does anyone have experience doing this or have any ideas on a better approach?
Thanks!

Comment: This is unclear. How do you define access to the Internet? Are you trying to find out whether certain resource in your VPC has access to the Internet? If so, you will need to check SGs, NACLs, ... as well. Or are you trying to find out if a certain subnet has a route to the Internet? Also note that route tables are attached to subnets, not to the VPC. You can have multiple subnets in your VPC where some of them have route to the Internet and some of them don't, whether ingress or egress.

Comment: How do you define "have internet access"? If you mean "could possibly have internet access", then simply select any VPC that has an Internet Gateway. If you need to know for each specific resource, then you'd have to check Route Tables, Security Groups, NACLs and the actual software installed on the instance (eg it might have a firewall configured).

Comment: AWS is currently working on a project called provable-security (https://aws.amazon.com/de/security/provable-security/) which maybe is already capable of determining internet accessibility... I do not know for sure. I only know that you can test the other direction using AWS Inspector's Network Reachability Test (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/inspector/latest/userguide/inspector_network-reachability.html), because that is what they teach us is in the AWS Security Specialty Certification.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can check the route table and all resources related, but you will not really prove you can access internet from it.
To prove it you need to access something on internet from a resource inside your VPC.

So I suggest you create an EC2 instance on-demand, access it via `SSH` and do a `curl` (or something similar) inside this instance.
If `curl` gives you the expected response, it is proved you have internet access.